# userRateLimitExceededUnreg for Google Anlalytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics API with the authentication method of Authsub. Recently we found most our customer faced userRateLimitExceededUnreg error.

The full error message was

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"userRateLimitExceededUnreg","message":"User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up","extendedHelp":"https://code.google.com/apis/console"}],"code":403,"message":"User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"}}
```

Don't know where to signup and how to increase the limit. Can anyone faced this kind of error ?